# Символьные массивы

Tags: c, массивы, строки, char

По каким правилам выполняется лексикографическое сравнение
символьных массивов?

Comment: По тем, которые задал программист. Или речь о строковых функциях типа `strcmp()`?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сравниваются коды, хранимые в символах, как беззнаковые целочисленные значения то есть происходит обычное последовательное сравнение кодов. Такое сравнение в С делают с помощью стандартных функций `strcmp`, которая сравнивает символьные массивы как строки, либо с помощью функции `memcpy`, которая сравнивает символьные массивы как набор байтов.

Если символьные массивы сравниваются как строки, то если все общие символы обоих строк совпадает, то считается меньшей строкой та, которая короче.

Вот демонстрационная программа на С

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char A[] = "A";
    char a[] = "a";
    char B[] = "B";
    char AA[] = "AA";

    printf( "%s\n", strcmp( A, B ) < 0 ? "true" : "false" );
    printf( "%s\n", strcmp( A, a ) < 0 ? "true" : "false" );
    printf( "%s\n", strcmp( B, a ) < 0 ? "true" : "false" );
    printf( "%s\n", strcmp( A, AA ) < 0 ? "true" : "false" );

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль

```
true
true
true
true
```

И аналогичная программа на C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>

int main() 
{
    char A[] = "A";
    char a[] = "a";
    char B[] = "B";
    char AA[] = "AA";

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << ( std::strcmp( A, B ) < 0 ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << ( std::strcmp( A, a ) < 0 ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << ( std::strcmp( B, a ) < 0 ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << ( std::strcmp( A, AA ) < 0 ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль

```
true
true
true
true
```

то есть, например, `'A'` меньше `'a'`, так как код `'A'` меньше кода `'a'` в таблице кодов `ASCII. (например, в  EBCDIC` будет противоположный результат), а строка "A" меньше строки "AA", так как первая строка короче второй строки, хотя коды всех ее символов (в данном случае одного символа) совпадают с соответствующими кодами второй строки.

Comment: В `EBCDIC` кодировки "A" > "a", поэтому вывод в системе с `EBCDIC` кодировкой.  `true false false true`

Comment: @Yaroslav Хорошее замесание, я что-то запамятовал.:)

Comment: **Сравниваются коды, хранимые в символах, как беззнаковые целочисленные значения** - всё далеко не так просто! Подумайте, к примеру, о беззнаковом значении кода кода буквы "ё"  в разных кодировках.

Comment: @Sergey Что вы хотите сказать?

Comment: Я хочу сказать, что для кодирования кирилицы используется (ЕМНИП) пять (!!!) разных кодировок (ср866б ср1251, КОИ-8R, ДКОИ, ISO8859-5, UTF...).  И мало того, что эти кодировки все разные по значениям кодов, так ещё и буквы кирилицы в них идут в РАЗНОМ порядке.

Comment: @Sergey И что? Как это связано с моим ответом?

Comment: Если принять Ваш ответ, то получается, что результат сравнения слов "Арбуз" и "Ёж" будет зависеть от того, в какой кодировке набита ваша программа.... :-) Я же говорю -всё значительно сложнее!

Comment: @Sergey Все правильно. Результат будет зависеть от того, какие коды имеют данные символы. Это и называется лексикографическим сравнением в языке C, и указанные в моем ответе функции так и сравнивают. Им совершенно безразлично, какие символы соответствуют заданным кодам.

Comment: Я не готов затевать холливар по поводу того, что  **называется лексикографическим сравнением в языке C**.  Если Вас действительно интересует ответ на этот вопрос, то посмотрите раздел 7 стандарта POSIX IEEE Std 1003.1. Я думаю, Вы не станет отрицать, что язык С  должен соответсвовать требованиям этого стандарта, так как он есть его основа.

Comment: @Sergey Вы могли бы уточнить, что именно противоречит этому стандарту в C?:)

Comment: **что именно противоречит этому стандарту в C** - ничего. А вот Ваш ответ - противоречит и вводит в заблуждение. TS спаршивал именно о ЛЕКСИКОГРАФИЧЕСКОЙ сортировке, а она выполняется по правилам, заданным в LC_COLLATE, а не по кодам символов.

Comment: @Sergey Вы все извращаете. Во-первых, автор вопроса спрашивал по сравнение символьных массивов, а не про сортировку. А это совершенно разные вещи. И массивы сравниваются в C и в C++ в соответствии с лексикографическом порядком, то есть в соответствии со значением кодов символов. Это, кстати сказать, не зависит от того, символьный массив или нет. А сравнение в соответствии с таблицей COLLATE - это уже специальное сравнение, которое должен дополнительно задавать пользователь и при сравнении дополнительно должен указывать локаль. Так что мой ответ совершенно корректный.

Comment: @Sergey Именно функции strcmp и memcpy выполняют лексикографическое сравнение. А сравнение в соответствии с специфической локалью не называется лексикографическим, а так и называется специфическим сравнением относительно локали. И для этого используются совсем другие функции, как например "The strcoll function compares the string pointed to by s1 to the string pointed to by
s2, both interpreted as appropriate to the LC_COLLATE category of the current locale."

Comment: @Sergey Даже само название функции strcoll включает в себя подслово collate. :)

Comment: @Sergey Поэтому когда в C и в C++ говорят про лексмкографическое сравнение, то имеют в виду стандартные функции strcmp и memcmp, а также стандартный алгоритм std::lexicographical_compare, которые просто попарно сравнивают значения, хранящиеся в массивах. Если вас попросят написать код, где лексикографически сравниваются символьные массивы, и вы вместо strcpy или memcpy будете использовать функцию strcoll, то вас не поймут.:)

Comment: @Sergey Лексикографический порядок, это тот порядок, который устанавливается оператором <. Этот оператор для объектов типа  char сравнивает коды этих символов. Когда используются стандартные функции C для сравнения символьных массивов, то объекты типа char сравниваются как объекты типа unsigned char. Все. Точка.

Answer (score 2):

Операция сравнения массивов в языке `C` отсутствует, независимо от их типа. Поэтому как программист захочет, так он и будет их сравнивать. Например, по длине :)

Если же речь идёт о [функциях стандартной библиотеки, работающих со строками](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string), то их поведение описано для каждой группы явно.

Например, про [strncmp()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncmp) сказано:

> The sign of the result is the sign of the difference between the
>   values of the first pair of characters (both interpreted as unsigned
>   char) that differ in the arrays being compared
>   ...
>   **This function is not locale-sensitive**

Описание [strcoll()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcoll) говорит:

> Compares two null-terminated byte strings **according to the current locale** as defined by the LC_COLLATE category ... Collation order is the dictionary order: the position of the letter in the national alphabet (its equivalence class) has higher priority than its case or variant. Within an equivalence class, lowercase characters collate before their uppercase equivalents and locale-specific order may apply to the characters with diacritics. In some locales, groups of characters compare as single collation units. For example, "ch" in Czech follows "h" and precedes "i", and "dzs" in Hungarian follows "dz" and precedes "g".

Аналогичная ситуация с парой `wcsncmp()`/`wcscoll()`, и т.д. В общем, читайте документацию, там всё подробно расписано.

Comment: Хочу только уточнить, что **документация** это не man на конкретную функцию, а стандарт POSIX IEEE Std 1003.1-2008, 2016 Edition, глава 7. Вот там всё расписано абсолютно точно.

Comment: Вы правы, спасибо, разобравшись понял,что имелл ввиду функцию strcmp()